# Help understanding the definition of "Better late than never"

Tags: idioms, time

[image]

Shouldn't there be completing instead of doing ? Because to do something after the expected time sounds like doing something at that time.

Comment: It's just a matter of how you (choose to) interpret something like *I arrived after the expected time.* Ordinarily you'd assume I meant I was ***late*** (the clock time when I arrived was *after* the time at which I *should* have already been there). But it *could* be interpreted *in some contexts* as meaning there was an expected amount of time (duration) for that journey, and I arrived *exactly* on time at the point when that timespan had elapsed.

Comment: How can "to do something **after** the expected time" be equal to "do something **at** that time"? I don't understand the question..

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Suppose you promised to go to a friend's concert, but for some reason you end up only being there for the last ten minutes.  Your friend assumed you would be there for the *entire* concert, but at least you got there late instead of missing it entirely -- that is, "better late than never". There are many similar situations where it might be better to be late than not go at all.

Of course, this is just an *expression*, and not a *recommendation*.  There are many other situations where you'd better be there on time -- like, for example, your own wedding.  In this case "better late than never" might not be a very good excuse.